# I am not able to improve LCP, attached performance screenshot

Tags: google-chrome, pagespeed, google-pagespeed, web-performance

[image]

I have tried a lot.
I am even pre-loading essential CSS & JS.
My LCP (Largest Contentful paint) is the large Image that one can see in the middle which I am pre-loading.
Still after loading, it takes a while to paint. Don't know the reason.
Maybe because I am using x-zoom JS library or some other JS trying to alter it?

Comment: looking at the tiny timeline it appears LCP is rendering the whole page at once, do you have a loading spinner etc. You may be preloading critcal CSS and JS but are you **inlining** it as that is required for fastest render times. Do you have this on a server so can look at it further as a screenshot of the performance tab isn't much to go on.

Comment: yes, thanks for reply.. in the above URL, please use `wakefit.co` instead of `localhost/consumer-wakefit`.. waiting for your help.

Answer (score 1):

According to Core Web Vitals, the common causes of poor LCP are:

- Slow server response times
- Render-blocking JavaScript and CSS
- Slow resource load times
- Client-side rendering

Here are some points I would like to shed lights on:

1. The `Time To First Byte (TTFB)` is not bad but can be enhanced. Try to reduce the initial server response time.
2. Leverage browser caching of static assets. The WebP images are not cached.
3. Preload key requests. For example, try to Preload the below resources:

   /fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff

   /fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.7.0
   /assets/FreightTe….woff2

   /fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf
4. Minify your `Fancybox` stylesheets.
5. Minify your `main_combined_footer.js` file and `Fancybox` JS files.

On another hand and as a side note that is not related to the topic, your site is missing common security headers. It would be good if you add the below in addition to the `X-XSS-Protection` you've included:

1. Strict Transport Security
2. X Content-Type Options
3. X Frame Options
4. Content Security Policy

Answer (score 1):

When looking at the production site, it seems that there are some straightforward reasons that LCP is poor.

https://waterfaller.dev/?url=https://www.wakefit.co/

Here are is one specific,

The issue is that this image april-2021-salaryday-tile.webp is missing height and width attributes which can cause layout shift as the image loads.

Then I think that the main reason is that your images are taking forever to download. If you look at the waterfall, all the images are requested at a quick start time, but then there is a VERY long download time.

I would start there then retest.

Comment: I agree that missing height & width cause layout shifts.. but it cannot cause it to take longer time to load.. I still wonder why because its only 34KB..